# Convergence Question

Tags: asymptotics, central-limit-theorem, slutsky-theorem

Suppose that $X_m \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $W_m \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ be a sequence of random variables such that the following asymptotic statements are true

\begin{equation*}
   \begin{aligned}
        \sqrt{m}\left(X_{m}-X_{0}\right) &\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Omega) \\
         W_{m} &\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} W_{0}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

where $W_0$ is a constant. I want to find the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt{m}\left(W_{m} X_{m}-W_{0} X_{0}\right)$, so I proceed as follows.

\begin{equation*}   
   \begin{aligned}
        \sqrt{m}\left(W_{m} X_{m}-W_{0} X_{0}\right)&=\sqrt{m}\left(W_{m} X_{m}-W_{m} X_{0}+W_{m} X_{0}-W_{0} X_{0}\right) \\
        &= \sqrt{m}\left(W_{m} X_{m}-W_{m} X_{0}\right)+\sqrt{m}\left(W_{m}-W_{0}\right) X_{0}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Using Slutsky's theorem, the first term has the following asymptotic distribution.
\begin{equation} 
  \sqrt{m}\left(W_{m} X_{m}-W_{m} X_{0}\right) \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow} W_0Z \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, W_0 \Omega W_0^{\top}\right).
\end{equation}

For the second term we have,

\begin{equation} 
 \sqrt{m}\left(W_{m}-W_{0}\right) X_{0}=o_{p}(1).
\end{equation}

So the claim is that, $\sqrt{m}\left(W_{m} X_{m}-W_{0} X_{0}\right) \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow} W_0 Z$. I have the following 3 questions

1. Is it ok to add/subtract terms as I did by adding and subtracting $W_mX_0$ and splitting the expression into 2 separate terms
2. Is it ok to say the second term is random variable that converges to zero ?
3. Indeed I don't know the rate at which $W_m \stackrel{p} {\rightarrow} W_0$. What happens under the more stringent condition, $W_m \stackrel{a.s.} {\longrightarrow} W_0$ ?

Comment: $W$'s should be $W_0$'s.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. No, consider a simple example: $W_m =m^{-\frac{1}{3}} = o(1) \subset o_p(1).$

Comment: Is $W_0$ a constant or could it be a non-degenerate random variable?

Comment: @Michael I changed $W$ to $W_0$

Comment: @Thomas. Indeed $W_0$ is a constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. No. You don't say why $\sqrt{m}(W_m-W_0)X_0$ would be $o_p(1)$, and it's not true in general.  The fact that $W_m\stackrel{p}{\to}W_0$ doesn't imply any rate of convergence. Suppose, for example, that $W_0=17$ and that $W_m$ has mean $17+m^{-1/4}$ and variance $m^{-1/4}$. Then $W_m$ converges to $W_0$ in probability but $\sqrt{m}(W_m-W_0)$ does not converge.

Now, the question whether that's a local counterexample or a global counterexample: is the *result* false or is it just that the *proof* is wrong?

At least if $W_0$ is constant the result is still true, as you can see using almost-sure representations. By the almost-sure representation theorem, there are versions of $X_m$, $X$, $Z$, and $W_m$, possibly defined on a different probability space, such that
$$\sqrt{m}(X_m-X_0)\stackrel{as}{\to}Z$$
and
$$W_m\stackrel{as}{\to}W_0$$

For these versions
$$\sqrt{m}(W_mX_m-W_0X_0)\stackrel{as}{\to}W_0Z$$
and so for these versions
$$\sqrt{m}(W_mX_m-W_0X_0)\stackrel{d}{\to}W_0Z$$
and since that's a result depending only on distributions for each $m$
$$\sqrt{m}(W_mX_m-W_0X_0)\stackrel{d}{\to}W_0Z$$
for any sequences having those distributions.

[the proof doesn't go through if $W_0$ is non-degenerate random variable; I don't know if the result is true, but I suspect not]

Comment: Is it possible to do this without invoking the "almost sure representation theorem"? I am not sure how well it works for multivariate vectors. I also changed the question to include $W_m \stackrel{a.s.}{\longrightarrow} W_0$

Comment: You should be able to do it using the continuous mapping theorem, but there are versions of the a.s. representation theorem not only for multivariate vectors but even for infinite-dimensional ones.   Have a.s. convergence of the $W_m$ doesn't make any difference at all -- what matters is whether $W_0$ is a constant or a random variable.